# Notifications via socket.io on php site

Tags: php, node.js, curl, socket.io

I am building a website in PHP that handles the sessions in Redis in JSON format.

This way the session can be accessed by both the PHP interpreter and a node.js server.

What I am trying to do is now to add notifications in said website; the procedure I was thinking of is the following: (just figure it as a simple friend request to simplify it all)

1. user A sends friend request.
2. PHP uses cURL to say to node.js service to send notification
3. user B gets a notification because he is connected to node.js via socket.io

What are the general guidelines to achieve this? Because it looks clear to me that if user A and B are in different servers, it will be impossible to scale horizontally;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a you could make use of Web Sockets here with a Publication / Subscription protocol, architecture.

You get Server client functionality with web sockets.
Node is a perfect choice for a websocket server, lots of small IO.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_sockets

I'm wouldn't think if the shared session is required for php - node communication, just have your clients push requests through the socket and handle the reposes as needed.

Comment: I already know I need to use web sockets; in fact I mentioned socket.io. My question is more of a "pseudocode " typeOf, as I am having quite an hard time with socket.io, especially when it comes to scalability.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear first time reading. It might be beneficial to keep the socket server un-aware of the session. where are your issues with scaling ?

Comment: I though the sessions are important to let node know who to send the message to? Correct me if I'm wrong. The issue is if course if the two users are on two different node servers, how can server a send the message to server b?

Comment: The simple answer is it can't without shared database or storage, My preference would be to write the messages to the database and have node servers check for new message and update a boolean if it's been pushed & received by the client. You could do the same with files, tho this wouldn't scale easily.

Comment: to have node check for messages automatically, it needs to know which user's messages to look after, so for this solutionI think I'd still need the session, to get their ID. but that is not a problem I guess

Comment: Yeah the node server that a client connects to would have the a user id associated with their socket object. You would then need to trigger a push event checking if all client ids against the database if they have messages push them through the socket, if not skip.

Comment: I've not much expierence with web sockets, I've only done some testing / introduction with Ratchet http://socketo.me/ *pure php websocket server. But they cover the basics and general structure for a pub/sub setup. I would recommend reading.

Comment: +1 for introducing socketo.me. although your answer does not really answer the question.

Comment: not necessarily, when your client connects over web socket you can send info that's identifying them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach you propose sounds quite reasonable. However, instead of doing a direct request to the service, you could consider using a message queue (zeromq, rabbitmq, whatever) which would allow you to scale it more easily as you can easily add logic to the queue processing to pass the message to the correct node instance.

I managed to get 1400 concurrent connections with socket.io on a cheap VPS with no special configuration so even with no tricks it should scale quite well. In my case most of these connections were also sending and receiving data almost constantly. It could probably have handled more than that, 1400'ish was simply the max number of users I happened to get.

Though I'd worry more about getting all those users first ;)

Comment: Yea, I understand that the approach is the right one, the problem is that I've just gone *that* far, got no idea on how to implement a code. If you could help me with some pseudocode, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Use Redis's built in pub-sub capability. When the PHP server gets a request, it publishes it to a channel set up for that purpose. Each of your node servers subscribes to that channel and checks if the user involved is connected to it. If so, it sends the notification via socket.io. As a bonus, you avoid an extra network connection and your overall logic is simplified.

Answer (score 0):

simply setup ur database as per required then whenever a activity is made just tell ur node js to transfer the related information through redis to php and make a process and in make a response back from php to node via channel keep checking the notification from table and show